# Print N decimals of float or double

Tags: java, decimal-point

What is the best way to write something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt();
double d = 5.123456789123456789;
System.out.printf("%.nf", d);
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to do? do you want to print the double d n-times?

Comment: Check out NumberFormat and DecimalFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string is just a `String` that you can create at runtime. E.g.

```
System.out.printf("%." + n + "f", d);
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the number of decimal places for a double, you can use java DecimalFormat.

As the number of decimal places is only known at runtime, you need to generate to pattern for the DecimalFormat at runtime also.

So:

```
    int n = 5; // or read in from user input
    String decimalFormatPattern = ".";
    for (int i =0 ; i < n; ++i) { // generate pattern at runtime
        decimalFormatPattern += "#";
    }
    // format pattern would be .#####
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(decimalFormatPattern);

    double d = 5.123456789123456789;
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));
```